# Linear Least Square Equation is Strictly Convex

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-regression

I know linear least square equation $\|y−X\beta\|^2$ can have multiple solutions since it is NOT a strictly convex equation. How to prove it is only a convex function and NOT a strictly convex function?

Comment: It depends on whether the matrix has full column rank or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that the Hessian matrix of $g(\beta) = \|y-X\beta\|^2$ is 
$$
2X'X,
$$
hence you can check whether $2X'X$ is strictly positive or not. As such, let $b\in \mathbb{R}^p$, then 
$$
b'X'Xb=(Xb)'Xb=c'c=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2\ge 0.
$$
Whether $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2$ is strictly positive or not, depends on the rank of $X'X$. If $\rho(X'X)=p$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 > 0$, otherwise there is only weak inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I got the overall idea. Although I didn't understand the last statement that rank of the matrix X'X needs to be p for strict inequality. I think I need to brush up my linear algebra skills to understand that.